# Can I assume a new keyboard works with linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard

I'm buying a new keyboard, specifically HyperX alloy pro. It obviously works for windows 10 but I see no information on linux use.

Can I assume it works for linux? By works I mean the typing works, I don't care about led lightning, software etc. Does it matter if it's ubuntu, arch etc?

Comment: If you don't care of "gadget" functions  99% of keyboards will works

Comment: A couple of reviews: http://www.notebookreview.com/review/kingston-hyperx-alloy-fps-keyboard-review-cherry-mx-red/ ........and.......... https://linuxreviews.org/HyperX_Alloy_FPS_Mechanical_Gaming_Keyboard

Answer (score 1):

The [USB Human Interface Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class#Keyboards) class is [standardized](https://www.usb.org/hid), therefore the keyboard should work.

Maybe the fancy features like macros and LED lighting (assuming this keyboard has them) won't work; I couldn't find much info in a cursory search.